# develop OpenWeave device to integrate with Nest products directly

Tags: smart-device, openthread

I have read this [OpenThread using Nest Learning Thermostat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839496/openthread-using-nest-learning-thermostat).
I am wondering if there is any update after near 2 years.
We try to developing a smart lock as a Weave-enabled device to participate in Nest Fabric.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are no updates to the answer in your link.